# Trying to use reflection to concatenate lists of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection, c#-7.0

I have below class

```
public class HydronicEquipment
{
    public List<LibraryHydronicEquipment> Source { get; set; }
    public List<LibraryHydronicEquipment> Distribution { get; set; }
    public List<LibraryHydronicEquipment> Terminals { get; set; }
}
```

and then i have the below class for "libraryHydronicEquipment"

```
public class LibraryHydronicEquipment : IEquipmentRedundancy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public RedundancyStatus RedundancyStatus { get; set; }
    public EquipmentRedundancy EquipmentRedundancy { get; set; }
 }
```

I am trying to concatenate the list of "**LibraryHydronicEquipment**" objects available from all three properties (i.e) from source, distribution and terminal and General concatenate method will looks like as this below

```
 var source = hydronicEquipment.Source;
 var distribution = hydronicEquipment.Distribution;
 var teriminals = hydronicEquipment.Terminals;
 Source.Concat(Distribution).Concat(Terminals)
```

I am trying to achieve the same using reflection and the code looks like as below

```
 foreach (var (systemName, hydronicEquipment) in hydronicSystemEquipment)
 {
     bool isFirstSystem = true;                   
     var equipmentList = new List<string> { "Source", "Distribution", "Terminals" };
     var redundancyequipmentList = GetRedundancyEquipment(hydronicEquipment, equipmentList);                                  
  }
```

and the method `GetRedundancyEquipment` is looks like below

```
private static IEnumerable<IEquipmentRedundancy> GetRedundancyEquipment(HydronicEquipment hydronicEquipment, List<string> equipmentList)
{
    IEnumerable<IEquipmentRedundancy> equipmentRedundancies = new List<IEquipmentRedundancy>();
    dynamic equipmentResults = null;
    foreach(var equipment in equipmentList)
    {
        var componentList = hydronicEquipment.GetType().GetProperty(equipment).GetValue(hydronicEquipment, null) as IEnumerable<IEquipmentRedundancy>;
       equipmentResults =  equipmentRedundancies.Concat(componentList);
    }
    return equipmentResults;
}
```

The problem here is even though i have Source is having  list of objects and Distribution is having list of objects, the `equipmentResults` is giving only one object instead of list of concatenated objects.

I am trying to return the `IEnumerable<IEquipmentRedundancy>` at the end using reflection method but it seems not working with the above code.

Could any one please let me know how can i achieve this, Many thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say 'giving only one object', what object does it give you?

Comment: it is just giving single `IEquipmentRedundancy` in turn it is sending last object

Comment: What about adding a readonly property 

```public class HydronicEquipment
{
    public List<LibraryHydronicEquipment> Source { get; set; }
    public List<LibraryHydronicEquipment> Distribution { get; set; }
    public List<LibraryHydronicEquipment> Terminals { get; set; }
    public List<LibraryHydronicEquipment> AllSources { get { return Source.Concat(Distribution).Concat(Terminals) } }
}```

Comment: @RodRamírez,  I am trying to achieve using reflection

Comment: @EnigmaState check my comment above

Comment: @RodRamírez , sorry I cannot change the entity now

Comment: Since you can't change the entity, can you do one thing and change your reflection code to do `as IEnumerable<LibraryHydronicEquipment>`, I'm assuming it maybe doesn't like the implicit cast to `IEquipmentRedindancy`

Comment: @James, i need to use the same method  for other classes where IEquipmentRedundancy implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetRedundancyEquipment` should preserve your values instead of reassign the reference with each iteration. Here's the fixed version:

```
private static IEnumerable<IEquipmentRedundancy> GetRedundancyEquipment(HydronicEquipment hydronicEquipment, List<string> equipmentList)
{
    IEnumerable<IEquipmentRedundancy> equipmentRedundancies = new List<IEquipmentRedundancy>();
    var equipmentResults = new List<IEquipmentRedundancy>();
    foreach (var equipment in equipmentList)
    {
        var componentList = hydronicEquipment.GetType().GetProperty(equipment).GetValue(hydronicEquipment, null) as IEnumerable<IEquipmentRedundancy>;
        equipmentResults.AddRange(equipmentRedundancies.Concat(componentList));
    }
    return equipmentResults;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we look at what you're doing in `GetRedundancyEquipment()` it becomes clear.

First you create `equipmentRedundancies = new List<IEquipmentRedundancy>();`

Then you *never* modify `equipmentRedundancies` - e.g. via `Add()`. It remains an empty list until it goes out of scope and is garbage collected.

In a loop you then repeatedly make this assignment `equipmentResults =  equipmentRedundancies.Concat(componentList);`

That is to say: Assign to `equipmentResults` the concatenation of `componentList` to `equipmentRedundancies`.

Note that `Concat()` is a lazily evaluated linq method. When you actually enumerate it results are produced. It doesn't modify anything, it's more like  a description of how to produce a sequence.

So each time through the loop you're assigning a new IEnumerable that describes a concatentaion of an empty list followed by the property that you retrieved with reflection to `equipmentResults`. Then at the end you return the final one of these concatenations of an empty list and retrieved property.

If you want all of them together, you should concatenate each of them to the result of the previous concatenation, not to an empty list.

Comment: Yeah thanks, that is what i am looking for but how to get previous concatenation list is where i am stuck at. Could you have any sample snippet you would throw.

Comment: @EnigmaState ... you've already assigned the result to an IEnumerable. Just use that - not the list. In fact, I'd say don't use the list _at all_. If you're not using a list as a list, but just as an empty starting point for some linq composition then use `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`

Comment: ok do you mean this `equipmentRedundancies.Concat(componentList);` but i need to return concatenated list at the end of method and getting warning as well for not returning  concatenated object